# why is the size of an Avl tree O(n)?

Tags: avl-tree

The AVL tree only has O(logn) for all his operation since its a balanced tree. The height is O(logn) as well so how come the size of the AVL tree itself is O(n) can someone explain that to me? I know that you have to to calculate left subtree+1(for root)+ right subtree to get the size of the whole tree.Howevery the operation to get for exmaple the size of the right subtree is log(n) and  logn + logn+1 doesnt equal O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about time complexity or space complexity, we mean the rate at which the time or space requirements change with respect to the size of input. Eg. when we say O(1), we mean regardless of the size of input, the time (in case of time complexity) or space (in case of space complexity) is constant. So O(1) does **not** mean 1 second or 1 minute. It just means constant with respect to input size. If you plot the execution time against different input sizes, you'd get a horizontal line. Similar is the case for O(n) or O(log n).

Now with this understanding, let's talk about AVL tree. AVL tree is a balanced binary search tree. Therefore the average time complexity to search for a node in the tree is O(log n). Note that to search a node, you don't visit every single node of the tree (unlike a LinkedList). If you had to visit every single node, you'd have said the time complexity is O(n). In case of AVL tree, every time you find a mismatch, you discard one half of the tree and move on to search in the remaining half.

In the worst case you'd make one comparision at each level of the tree i.e. equal to the hight of the tree, so the search time complexity is O(log n). Size of left tree is **not** O(log n).

Talking about size, you do need space to store each node. if you have to store 1 node, you'd need 1 unit space, for 2 nodes, 2 units, for 3 nodes, 3 units and so on. This unit could be anything 10 bytes, 1 KB, 5 KB anything. Thr point is if you plot the space requirement of the input in computer memory against the number of trees, all you get is a linear graph starting at zero. That's O(n).

Too further clarify, while computing the time or space complexity of an algorithm, if the complexity comes as O(1 + log n + 4n + 2^n + 100), we call it O(2^n) i.e. we take the largest value because we are not calculating the absolute value, we are calculating the rate of change with respect to the size of input and thus the largest value is what matters.

If you talk about the time complexity of the algorithm to calculate the size of the tree, you need yo visit every node in the tree. Since the total number of nodes is n, it will be O(n).

Comment: I just wanted to hear the last sentence but I appreciate the building up to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the size of a tree you will have to traverse each node once present in the tree.Hence if there are n nodes in a tree traversing each node once will eventually lead to the time complexity of o(n).